# ga:adCost returning 0 in query builder

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have been using Google Analytics Query Builder Tool(https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to try and get my Ad cost within a date range but the query is returning 0.

Could anyone advise what I am doing wrong please?

I am getting values correctly from ga:users ect so the builder is working correctly.

Comment: Are you setting any segment in your query params?

Comment: I have tried when messing around in the query builder but has same result. Im new to Google API so just trial and testing at the moment. What segments do you recommend?

Comment: Ad cost queries have a reported bug that return 0. Try to set a ransom segment and then try without it. Thats how we made it work.